# LSTM with optuna, getting a high rmse

Tags: python, lstm

My first time doing an LSTM and optuna. I wanted to use optuna to find the best values of batch size, epoch and optimizer. But when I do, I get a rmse value of 8.34 when I get a naive prediction of 0.69 and with a model with a set value of batch size of 8, epoch 4000 and optimizer SGD I get a rmse of 0.28. I could use just that model but I wanted to use optuna to get optimal (or near_optimal) values of the parameters rather than random values.

The script I use is:

```
def calculate_rmse(model, loader):
   predictions = []
   targets = []
   for X, y in loader:
       y_pred = model(X)
       predictions.append(y_pred)
       targets.append(y)

    predictions = torch.cat(predictions, dim=0)
    targets = torch.cat(targets, dim=0)
    rmse = torch.sqrt(loss_fn(predictions, targets))
    return rmse.item()


def objective(trial):
    optimizer_name = trial.suggest_categorical("optimizer", ["adam", "SGD", 
    "RMSprop", "Adadelta"])
    epochs = trial.suggest_int("epochs", 100, 4000,step=100, log=False)
    batchsize = trial.suggest_int("batchsize", 8, 40,step=16, log=False)

    model = LSTMmodel().double()
    train_loader, valid_loader = get_loader(train, batchsize)
                              
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        model.train()
        for X_batch, y_batch in train_loader:
            y_pred = model(X_batch)
            loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y_batch)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
    # Validation
        if epoch % 100 != 0:
           continue

        model.eval()
        with torch.no_grad():
            valid_rmse = calculate_rmse(model, valid_loader)
        

    weights = list(model.named_parameters())

# Handle pruning based on the intermediate value.
if trial.should_prune():
    raise optuna.exceptions.TrialPruned()

trial.set_user_attr(key="best_model_weights", value=weights)
return valid_rmse

def callback(study, trial):
    if study.best_trial.number == trial.number:
        study.set_user_attr(key="best_model_weights", 
                        value=trial.user_attrs["best_model_weights"])

study = optuna.create_study(direction="minimize")
study.optimize(objective, n_trials=100, timeout=None, callbacks=[callback])

pruned_trials = study.get_trials(deepcopy=False, states=[TrialState.PRUNED])
complete_trials = study.get_trials(deepcopy=False, states=[TrialState.COMPLETE])
print("Best trial:")
trial = study.best_trial

print("  Value: ", trial.value)

print("  Params: ")
for key, value in trial.params.items():
    print("    {}: {}".format(key, value))
```

The output is: Best trial: Value:  8.34076415009934 Params: optimizer: SGD epochs: 200 batchsize: 24. What am I doing wrong? and what can I do to improve the rmse? Thanks